# Using dll without using regasm command

Tags: c++, dll, tlb

I'm trying to use a C# dll from C++.
I was actually able to use the C# dll in C++ through the regasm command.

I want to use C# dll on my local PC as well as other PCs.
But every time I use it, I only know how to register it in a register through the regasm command.

[I tried]

1. Action done by putting dll and tlb files

[Local]RegAsm.exe C#.dll /tlb:C#.dll command was used to create a tlb file, and the dll and tlb files were used in the project I wanted by referencing the file and wrapped with a wrapper. -> Normal operation

[Remote] 14007 error is displayed when the tlb file and the existing dll file that appear after executing the regasm command are put in the folder with the project on another computer and run. -> Error when trying to run the file on another computer (probably confirmed to be a registry problem)

2. One action by putting a .tlh file and a .tli file
   We have confirmed that .tlh and .tli files are created in the user temp directory.
   The actual contents of this were COM values ​​and GUIDs, and when these two files were put into another computer project and used, the same error was displayed (14007)

[question]

1. (Ultimate inquiry) I want to make it work on other computers without using the regasm command.
2. Compiling the file creates a .tlh file and a .tli file in the user's temp directory. Can I use this?

Comment: I seem to recall having done this at some point, but I don't remember the details. Some possible hints in these answers: [Is registration-free activation possible for EXE (out-of-process) COM servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211345/is-registration-free-activation-possible-for-exe-out-of-process-com-servers) [How to use Registration free COM dll in dot net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209910/how-to-use-registration-free-com-dll-in-dot-net).

Comment: I want to get a quick solution to the above problem